# How to change active color of BottomNavigationView in material3

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material3

[image]

How to change active color of BottomNavigationView

remove or change color for active item in BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a style, like this:

```xml
<style name="Custom.Indicator" parent="Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator">
    <item name="android:color">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

And then set it on you BottomNavigation, like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Custom.Indicator"
```